# Enabling the Gyroscope

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, gyroscope, accelerator

I have a webview that opens a site with WebGl or CCS3D. On this site there is a button that includes a gyroscope.

If you go to this site through the chrome and click on this button, the gyroscope turns on.
If you run the site through webview in the android app, then when you click the button
gyro, the site does not spin, as it does in the chrome.

Question: how to turn on the gyroscope on android, so that when you press the gyro button the site also rotates as in the chrome?

The following permissions are connected:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true" />
```

Code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    WebView webView;
    final String ulr="http://sfer***.com/hodite/";
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl(ulr);

        /*sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);*/


    }
```

Support me,pls.

Answer (score 0):

I think webview does not support gyroscope. Instead of using the default Webview, you can try to use **XWalkView** This will support the Gyroscope.
Add the below code in build.gradle

```
repositories {
//mavenLocal()
maven {
    url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
}}
```

Add the below line in dependencies

```
compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
```

Add in your layout file:

```
<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
    android:id="@+id/xwalkWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"/>
```

This will solve your problem. All the best !!.

Comment: Thanks,it works for me.
But I have a very big apk,why?
My first size is 1,5mb and my apk with this library is 50mb

Comment: The library takes size approx 45mb. You can generate 2 APK's and the size will get divided to 20-20mb each. Google play store will automatically manage which apk to be shown for which device. You can check this [link](https://github.com/yaroslav-v/crosswalk-embedded) for more details.